# Регулярные выражения python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Дана строка

```python
msg = 'name / https://stackoverflow.com | name2 + https://stackoverflow.com2 | name3 + https://stackoverflow.com3\nname4 * https://stackoverflow.com4 | name5 - https://stackoverflow.com5'
```

Как поделить строку на символе `"/"`, то есть, чтобы две новых переменных приняли следующие значения:

```python
title = 'name'
link = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```

Comment: Здесь несколько символов `/`. Дайте более точное условие, приведя примеры текстов и что в них найти в соответствии с меткой [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: 'dwdawd / https://stackoverflow.com | dwdawd2 + https://stackoverflow.com2 | dwdawd3 - https://stackoverflow.com3'

Comment: Используйте кнопку править. И примеры должны быть однозначные. У вас сказано по символу `/`, а во втором и третьем примерах его нет

Comment: подправил, посмотрите?

Comment: У вас всё ещё 1 пример, который противоречит предыдущему. Теперь всё, что идёт после первой ссылки, надо отбросить? Почитайте [описание метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/регулярные-выражения/info)

Comment: не отбросить, а поделить по знаку "|", и после этого делить на знаке "/" на две переменные.

Comment: В ваших интересах привести понятное другим условие, чтобы получить нужное решение. В третий раз одно и то же повторять не вижу смысла. Если какой-то ответ решает вопрос, то поставьте галку слева от него

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример регулярки через поиск значения.

Слева через `[^/]+` задается последовательность любых символов, кроме `/`, после `\s*` говорит, что пробелы могут быть от 0 до n и `http.+` для поиска ссылки начинающейся с `http`

Пример:

```
import re

msg = 'dwdawd / https://stackoverflow.com'
items = re.findall(r'([^/]+)\s*/\s*(http.+)', msg)
if items:
    title, url = items[0]
    print(title, url)
    # dwdawd https://stackoverflow.com
```

Немного "докрученный" пример:

```
import re

def parse(msg: str) -> tuple:
    items = re.findall(r'([^/]+)\s*/\s*(http.+)', msg)
    if items:
        title, url = map(str.strip, items[0])
        return title, url
    return '', ''


msg = 'dwdawd / https://stackoverflow.com'
print(parse(msg))
# ('dwdawd', 'https://stackoverflow.com')

msg = 'dwdawd/https://stackoverflow.com'
print(parse(msg))
# ('dwdawd', 'https://stackoverflow.com')

msg = 'dwdawd   / https://stackoverflow.com'
print(parse(msg))
# ('dwdawd', 'https://stackoverflow.com')

msg = '/ https://stackoverflow.com'
print(parse(msg))
# ('', '')

msg = 'dwdawd   /https://stackoverflow.com/http+'
print(parse(msg))
# ('dwdawd', 'https://stackoverflow.com/http+')
```

Comment: @АдильНогаев, если мой ответ вам помог, отметьте его как решенный :)

Comment: Можно еще вопрос? Если будет еще несколько таких строк в одном сообщении, но разделяться будут символом ' | ', как добавить в паттерн данный символ?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал предварительно сделать `split` по `|`, а после, в цикле, для каждой строки вызвать мой код с регуляркой. Типа: `for msg in text.split('|'): print(parse(msg))`

Comment: `http.+` не ищет именно ссылку, начинающуюся с `http`, а ищет просто непустую последовательность символов, начинающихся с `http`. Например, в `dwdawd /https://stackoverflow.com/http+` будет выделено `http+` второй группой

Comment: @dIm0n, спасибо, хорошее замечание :)

Comment: @АдильНогаев, обновил регулярку, причину посмотрите в комментарии dIm0n. Другой вариант выражения слева, это задать возможные значения, например: `[\w\s]+` -- это буквы, цифры, `_` и пробельные символы, но это не учитывает всякую пунктуацию и прочее -- их тоже нужно в `[]` добавлять

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом `split`:

```python
title, link = msg.split(' / ', maxsplit=1)
```

Метод разбивает строку, из объекта которой вызван на отрезки, разделённые символом, переданным ему в аргумент, причём кол-во анализируемых разделителей можно задать с помощью доп. аргумента `maxsplit`, и возвращает результат в виде списка таких отрезков. Python позволяет сразу положить элементы списка в нужные переменные, что я и сделал в своём примере.

Если подробнее, то `msg.split('/')` вернёт `['dwdawd', 'https://stackoverflow.com']`, а присваивание "положит" по соответствию нулевой элемент списка в переменную `title`, первый элемент списка – в переменную `link`. Можно расписать мой пример длиннее:

```python
result = msg.split(' / ', maxsplit=1)
title = result[0]
link = result[1]
```

Результат не изменится.

Comment: а если все такие пользователь отправит не ' / ' а слитно 'title/link' или 'title /link'?

Comment: ну или в целом отправит любой другой символ

Comment: @АдильНогаев, такое нужно заранее описывать в задаче :) Мы ведь не знаем какой формат данных может быть :)

Comment: @АдильНогаев про любой другой символ мне очень понравилось. Любой другой символ будет уже любым другим вопросом. Ваш вопрос был конкретно про такое разделение с таким символом. Понятно, что в теории пользователь может отправить вообще что угодно, тут уже Вам нужно делать валидацию входных данных.

Comment: @gil9red точно, спасибо. Давно не работал с этим, подзабылось.

Comment: @V-Mor, пожалуйста, самого это путало :)